# Normalization of tokens python

Tags: python, replace, token, lowercase, normalize

I need to transforms a token (e.g "Doesn't") to a lower case. If there is a negation ”n’t” in the end of the token, it should remove it.

I did come so far but it's wrong. How do I proceed?

```
def normalize(token):

    list = ["Doesn't", "Don't"]

    if token in list:

     print(list.lower())

    print(list.replace("n't", ""))

    return list

    print("Doesn't")
```

Comment: Please check the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit your requirements?

```
def normalize(token):
    token = token.lower()
    if token[-3:] == "n't":
        return token[:-3]
    else:
        return token
```

**Output:**

```
>>> normalize("Doesn't")
'does'
>>> normalize("Don't")
'do'
```

Comment: You’re welcome; if my answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the tick next to it.